# What is the equivalent of yield in jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In Ruby/Sinatra/Haml I would write:

```
%html{:lang => 'en'}
  %head
    %meta{:charset => 'utf-8'}
    %title= @title

  %body
    =yield
```

What would it look like in Node/Express/Jade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title= title

  body
    != body
```

Comment: Are you using a layout.jade file together with another file ie index.jade?

Comment: Thanks, @asev69 . Removed from examples as it's not what the question is about.